# comparing 2 large unsorted data files: algorithm with implementation

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting

This is not the actual problem I have. But I want to test boundaries in order to choose a best or even good strategy.

The theoretical problem is this:

I have 2 files, 2Tb (make it 4Tb if any better) each of keys, 1 line 1 string, but given with a strong encoder, which makes each entry very different.

I need to know if the 2 files shares some of these keys. We can assume low overlap so that the output is not a storage issue. Or in other words: I want to compare 2 large files.

In a dummy approach, what I would do is to split file1 in bunches, as big as my ram, and cycle on file2 to find matches. I would need to cycle on I/O quite a bit.

We might also assume that sorting "in place" is not available. It is an option if part of the algorithm.

I assume that mapreduce/hadoop might get a kind of solution, and the first obvious one is using a sorting algorithm, as in any case the keys uses characters. We would need to map on 25 alpha plus few alphanumeric.

But does exists any better approach?

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem, and it really depends on your needs and resources... If you can sort the files because you have the time and they are not modified, you can use a dichotomy algorithm. If sorting the files is impossible, a BTree index would be a better approach (this is what database engines usually use)

Comment: How long are lines? If they're e.g 2B lines of 1Kb each, then it may well pay to hash the strings to - say - 64 bits each and work with hash->line number pairs (16 bytes per line). Yes this is a great problem for map/shuffle/reduce.

Comment: The standard solution is to sort each file using an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), and then do the comparison with a simple merge. This would require that you have space to store the sorted versions of both files, plus the output of the merge phase (which presumably would contain just the duplicates). Come to think of it, you could do all of this with the GNU sort utility--no need to write any code.